# Cross browser datepicker for Angular2

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I've tried using Pikday for cross browser datepicker but I'm seeing some issues with dynamically generated date inputs while using Pikaday. So I'm trying to find any other cross browser datepicker.
Any suggestions/recommendations? Thank you.

Comment: pikaday is good. should not have errors. whats you code?

Comment: I use Bootstrap with all my Angular projects, and https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api provides everything you need to use components like the data picker.

Comment: @Gary, its not working for dynamically generated inputs. Have you ever tried using it with dynamic inputs?

Comment: you will have to show the code for any code help